# Android send DELETE JSON request

Tags: android, json

I want to delete certain object by sending JSON request. To delete the object, I will provide food_id, I try it on POSTMAN and the key is food_id and value is the id number and it works. But when try in android, it doesn't work. Really need help!!

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    String url = "http://52.10.237.82:8080/api/food";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("food_id","54fe3c37ad3ef6992000000b");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.DELETE, url, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Message: ", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Message: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Comment: The object isn't deleted when I run the program.

Comment: What does `Log.d("Message: ", response.toString())` print?

Comment: {"message":"Food deleted!"}  However, it is not deleted. I try on Postman, even though the food is not deleted, it will return this message

Comment: Well, the request seems to work fine. The problem is in the server side.

Comment: But when I try it on Postman, if I provide the food_id, the object can be deleted, is there any difference?